# How to purge all kafka data for fresh start in a dev environment

Tags: apache-kafka

Sometimes its necessary to fresh-start a kafka cluster with no data. when running a kafka inside docker containers this behavior is achieved for free.
How to do it with kafka process ? can i delete /var/log/kafka* and restart it ? is it ok to do so ?

BTW - i am using something like this :

```
# bash shell
# tl is a list of all topics
for t in $(cat tl); do 
 ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $ZOO --delete --topic $t
done
```

there are 2 problem with the above :

1. if hdd usage is 100%, then i got error when trying the kafka-topics.sh
2. its very inefficient if i have many topics

looking for a fast and clean way to do in dev envs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like this do the job

```
$ ###### stop and clear all brokers
$ sudo systemctl stop kafka.service zookeeper.service
$ sudo rm -rf /var/log/kafka-logs/*

$ ###### continue ONLY after finish the above on all brokers
$ sudo systemctl start zookeeper.service
$ sleep 10s # make sure zookeeper is ready
$ sudo systemctl start kafka.service
```

Comment: 100% the answer, but note that the exact directory where your logs are stored might be different than the directory in this answer.  You can check the exact directory of your logs in your server.properties file.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to temporary set `log.retention.ms` to low value, lets say 1000. This way you tell kafka to keep messages only one second before deleting it forever. You wait a little bit, kafka will delete all of your messages(all but not messages on active segments) and when that is done, you can revert that `log.retention.ms` settings.